# How to use mat-tab? mat-tab is not a known element error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

I am trying to use `mat-tab`. I have added the below code in html

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1"> <app-latest-article></app-latest-article></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">  <app-trending-article></app-trending-article> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In ts file

```
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
```

I am getting error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>  'mat-tab' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'mat-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   ("
>  </ngx-tabset> -->

Comment: Okay i have resolved the error by adding dependencies in app module file. But the mat-tab api doesnt work as expected. I dont know whats wrong. I was just a plain sample example. waste of time ..

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Add the import in your module.ts file and add it to imports (if you use several module.ts files, add it in the one which is responsible for your component).

```
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatTabsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: []
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: this has changed in angular 9+

Comment: the `MatTabsModule` has to be imported as `import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';` in 9+

Answer (score 21):

For Angular 9+:

```
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
```

in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I was getting error ***'mat-tab' is not a known element*** even after importing both modules
The fix for me was
`npm install --save @angular/cdk @angular/material`

Answer (score 5):

> > ### ***None of these solutions worked for me***

Keep in mind that @shildmaiden's solution is the most accurate solution. Our scenarios were just slightly different.

In my case, I tried to use `mat-tab` in a sub module. This means that adding the import to the `AppModule` like @shildmaiden's suggested in his above solution failed to work for me so I simply implemented his solution in my `mySubModuleName.module.ts` file instead and then it worked just fine.

---

For `Angular 9+` make sure to use this example unless of course the other answers are edited accordingly:

```
// Rather use this line:
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
// Instead of this line:
// import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatTabsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: []
})

export class MySubModuleName {}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the page using the tab group is not in the declarations of app.module.ts you get the same error. In addition to adding the MatTabsModule to the imports, add your page to the declarations:

```
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material';
import { YourPage } from './yourpage.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatTabsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    YourPage
  ],
  providers: []
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Tq

Answer (score 2):

***Posting just in case this helps anyone***

All of the above solutions are accurate but I faced a slightly different issue.

In my case, I forgot to add my component in the `declarations` array and I was using `mat-tab` inside that component which was causing the issue.

I added the route for that component but forgot to add it in declarations.

Below was what I did wrong:

Here are my component files with errors in the terminal:

**component.html** (Everything is fine here but the terminal shows an error)
[image: component.html]

**routing.module.ts** (Everything is fine here but the terminal shows an error)
[image: routing.module.ts]

**Cause of error**

**module.ts** (Missing component in declarations array)
[image: module.ts]

**________________________________________________________________________**

**The fix**

**module.ts** (Fixing the error and indicating with yellow lines)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears for me that is, when CDK and Material are the same version i have the less issues :

```
"@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3"
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3"
```